# video header in desktop view, image header in mobile view

Tags: headers

In twenty seventeen, is there an easy way to show video header in desktop view, and show image header in mobile view ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [wp_is_mobile()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_mobile/) to check if the user is viewing from mobile..

So, the code becomes:

```
if(wp_is_mobile()){
  //show image
}
else{
 // show video
}
```

Comment: Sorry i know that i can use IF or media query, but i am asking for a better solution than this. Twenty seventeen is using a function the_custom_header_markup() to create the headers, and i would like to do it that way somehow for the best practice

Comment: Man. I wish I'd found this earlier. Great way to serve different headers depending on device.

Answer (score 0):

First, add video header support on your theme.

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-header', array(
    'video' => true
) );
```

Next, add *the_custom_header_markup();* on Header area where you want to show the image / video header.

Finally, style your video header with some css like this.

```
.wp-custom-header iframe,
.wp-custom-header img,
.wp-custom-header video {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
}
```

The header will *auto-switch* to Image whenever user accessing your site from mobile devices. No need to add extra code to handle video / image banner switching.

[Source](https://smartcatdesign.net/articles/add-video-wordpress-theme-website/)

Comment: aha, thanks, i will check this a few hours later, need to go out right now

Comment: It seems like twenty seventeen switches from video to image on 768px width, and as far as i can see, this is hardcoded. So i ended up by programming - what i needed - myself